# Dynamic background image of a div in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to set a background image for a div through Vue.js.

I have tried this way but it doesn't work. I have done this until now:
[image]

In my web page display in this way[image]:

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say "directive".  [These](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html) are directives.

Comment: @BernardBorg thanks for your answer I want to add background-image in the template vuejs.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Please note that your approach did work. You just didn't set the width and height on the div so it didn't appear on the screen.

[Working here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hoover-xm4wf7?file=/src/App.vue)

Still, I would go with the following approach if you only need to set the backgroundImage with a dynamic url.

[Options API];

```js
<template>
  <div
    :style="{
      backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px',
    }"
  ></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      imageUrl:
        "Your image url",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Alternatively using the Composition API [script setup]

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const imageUrl = ref(
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"
);
</script>

<template>
  <div
    :style="{
      backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px',
    }"
  ></div>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks and there way <template>
  <div :style="{'background-image':'url(https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png)'}">
  </div>
</template> doesn't work?

Comment: Your div sitn' going to appear on the screen if you don't set the width and height of the div. Since you're setting the background-image your div will remain empty which results in its size being (0 x 0) and not appear on the screen.